Is there source that a person must not have any entangled hairs in his beard when immersing in the mikvah
BH
Is it true there is a law that says when a person enters a mikvah he must make sure that none of his hairs from his beard are tangled with one another or have any knots on the single strands? If yes where?

If he is. Being tovel to become a ger then all hilchos chaztitza that abbly to women will apply to men
